# 'cp:cannot access file' error in script?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

This is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
$REPORT_PATH='/data/operational/logs'
cp "$(`ls -t | head -1`)" "$REPORT_PATH/new_file"
```

This gives error '`cp:cannot access pda_param`'.

pda_param file is o/p of ls command.

But this command works when I run it from logs directory.
I have also granted full permission to logs directory.

Any ideas?

Comment: Remove $ (in second line) when you assign a string/value to variable.

Comment: `$()` and and `` are the same. Just use `"$(ls -t | head -1)"`

Comment: Yes, I have removed ``. Still getting error.
The command runs from logs folder though as before.

Comment: Can you update the question (remove backtics) and explain in what directory it doesn't work? When it works in the logs dir, then the pda_param file should also be in the logs dir. Or did you simplify the question and removed some variables?

Comment: cp "$REPORT_PATH/$(ls -t | head -1)" "$REPORT_PATH/new_file"